HAVE_WCSCMP not found in libarchive
I'm making a simple Windows program with CMake.
I use curl and libarchive in the program.
I download it directly from git with FetchContent as shown below and use it.
If I download curl first and then libarchive as shown below,
it says that it can't find HAVE_WCSCMP.
CMakeLists.txt
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    curl
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/curl/curl.git
    GIT_TAG curl-8_9_1
    EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(curl)
        
FetchContent_Declare(
    libarchive
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive.git
    GIT_TAG v3.7.4
    EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libarchive)

...

target_link_libraries(
    program 
    PUBLIC CURL::libcurl archive

)

On the other hand, if I download libarchive first, it finds wcscmp well.
I found the cause by checking the actual log through cmake --debug-trycompile, but I don't know why.
Log when curl was downloaded first.
    kind: "try_compile-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake:86 (try_compile)"
      - "build/_deps/libarchive-src/build/cmake/CheckFuncs.cmake:45 (CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS)"
      - "build/_deps/libarchive-src/CMakeLists.txt:211 (CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_GLIBC)"
    checks:
      - "Looking for wcscmp"
    directories:
      source: "D:/Work/tttt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-prtjq8"
      binary: "D:/Work/tttt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-prtjq8"
    cmakeVariables:
      CMAKE_C_FLAGS: "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS"
      CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG: "/Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /w14062 /w14254 /w14295 /w14296 /w14389 /w14505 /w14514 /w14702 /w14706 /Oi"
      CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS: "/machine:x64"
      CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: "D:/Work/tttt/build/_deps/libarchive-src/build/cmake"

Log when libarchive was downloaded first.
    kind: "try_compile-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake:86 (try_compile)"
      - "build/_deps/libarchive-src/build/cmake/CheckFuncs.cmake:45 (CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS)"
      - "build/_deps/libarchive-src/CMakeLists.txt:211 (CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS_GLIBC)"
    checks:
      - "Looking for wcscmp"
    directories:
      source: "D:/Work/tttt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ntfjzw"
      binary: "D:/Work/tttt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-ntfjzw"
    cmakeVariables:
      CMAKE_C_FLAGS: "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS"
      CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: "D:/Work/tttt/build/_deps/libarchive-src/build/cmake"

